# clearRect() undoes transparency of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have two canvases overlaid on top of each other like so:

```js
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
" width="720" height="480"></canvas>

<canvas id="trailCanvas" style="z-index: 0;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
" width="720" height="480"></canvas>
```

But the problem is that when I call clearRect() on the top most canvas, like so:

```js
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

then it makes my topmost canvas look *grey* not transparent anymore! Isn't clearRect() supposed to make the whole canvas clear and transparent again? What's going on? Would really appreciate any help!

Edit: Realized my mistake was in the CSS:

```css
    <style>
     * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
     canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
```

which makes the canvas background grey instead of transparent.

Comment: please include a jsfiddle or a jsbin :)

Comment: yes, clearRect removes all transparency. The issue must be with something else. Can you bring your current code down to the first instance where this happens?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/bh34r1av/ this shows that clearRect does indeed reset transparency

Comment: Wow you're right, I made a very silly error. I had included some weird CSS that made my canvas background grey after copying and pasting from some online tutorial. Don't think there's any need to include jsfiddle now, but next time I'll do so to make things easier.

Comment: maybe include that piece of css in an edit so I can write a proper answer and close the question?

Comment: Okay, just did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh34r1av/), `clearRect` successfully resets the alpha.

Chances are your problem has other sources, one of the most common being adding a `background-color` to a canvas in the CSS. To check for this, inspect the canvas with your devtools of choice, and see what the background properties are